# .NET MAUI Blazor - What to incorporate to it, Blazor Server or Blazor WASM as best practice?

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-maui

Good Day Everyone

I'm currently checking .NET MAUI Blazor App, and according to some tutorials, you can incorporate existing Blazor applications, currently, I have 2 different apps, one is made in Blazor Server and the other one is made in Blazor WASM, If I'm incorporating my apps to .NET MAUI Blazor what is the best practice to incorporate to it, Server or the WASM? sorry for the questions, I actually getting confused if .NET MAUI Blazor is a client app or a server-side app.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Maui Blazor is client-side. However it isn't exactly the same as writing for browser. Shuryno's answer is correct: its "Blazor Hybrid". Its a "UI" environment, interacting with user - so the components that make most sense are UI-related, or self-contained (don't access functionality that may not exist in the outer environment).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help you? They are talking about Blazor Hybrid, it is not Server nor Wasm. It runs natively using a webview for the razor pages. Its a third kind.

[Microsoft presentation of Blazor Hybrid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI058EA_maE&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oVGRpRwbMhUA0KAvMA2mLyN&index=1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-blazor-hybrid/